# Code gets stuck at wakelock,while registering to GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

It does not get registration id from GCM server the app does not give any error,this is my logcat.

```
    07-13 16:43:39.920: I/** pushAndroidActivity **(5310): inside oncreate() 
07-13 16:43:39.920: I/** pushAndroidActivity **(5310): started registration 
07-13 16:43:39.920: D/GCMRegistrar(5310): resetting backoff for com.example.registration_id
07-13 16:43:39.920: V/GCMRegistrar(5310): Registering app com.example.registration_id of senders 803641917196
07-13 16:43:42.735: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(5310): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
07-13 16:43:42.735: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(5310): GCM IntentService class: com.example.registration_id.GCMIntentService
07-13 16:43:42.735: V/GCMBaseIntentService(5310): Acquiring wakelock
```

This is the main Activity .i have used the existing gcm.jar file to use GCMRegistrar class methods.

```
package com.example.registration_id;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private String TAG = "** pushAndroidActivity **";
    EditText edittext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "inside oncreate() ");




        //check if registered,if not get registration id from GCM server
        if(GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this).equals(""))
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "started registration ");
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, "803641917206");

        }
        else
        {
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====  "+regId);

        edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
        edittext.setText(regId);
        }
    }




}
```

This is the service class-

```
package com.example.registration_id;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";



    //default constructor
    protected GCMIntentService(String senderId) {
        super(senderId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "error ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
```

onReceiver is being called which means you are getting a message back.

```
  protected GCMIntentService(String senderId) {
      super(senderId);                }
```

This is your problem. you must declare a public, no argument constructor for your GCMBaseIntentService subclass. Otherwise, your GCMIntentService class can't be constructed and used properly by the background services.

Why?

```
protected GCMIntentService(String senderID){
super(senderId);}
```

because this protected constructor isn't visible to the service class that handles all incoming intents, because it is in a different package.

Hardcode the senderId in a static constant in your GCMIntentService class because that will no longer change from google.

Comment: I have done as you said,but still stuck at wake lock. i have implemented a line in onRegistered(); method in the service class which should show the registration id in logcat

Comment: Make sure that you have this permission in your android manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: i have modified the manifest-                                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> still stuck at wake lock

Comment: My application is not going farward from acquiring WAKE LOCK.. I have also added permission in manifest but not working well..

Answer (score 1):

Note this : GCM IntentService class: com.example.registration_id.GCMIntentService

Where is the GCMIntentService class placed (in which package) ?

Check the manifest file to make sure you set up correct package for GCMIntentService.

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution too
Keep all GCM related class in the main package, where u r calling registration.

[Android Programming: GCMIntentService Stuck at WakeLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064337/android-programming-gcmintentservice-stuck-at-wakelock)